# Spatial and property search

Tags: file-geodatabase, java, software-recommendations, oracle-spatial

We have a lot of polygons (some of them contain holes) and there are also a lot of points inside different polygon, these data are processed as ESRI geodatabase format.

Now we have to do some spatial and property search in our JavaEE application which use the Oracle 11g as the database, for example, there is one kind of search, once use click in the map, we should return the points within the polygon where the mouse inside, and also we should filter the points by some additional properties.

And there maybe other spatial search in the future.

So I am not sure if I should use the Oracle Spatial in the application or we should use file geodatabase(*.gdb) directly?

1) Use oracle Spatial

Because we are not familiar with Oracle Spatial, so we do not know if there are any challenge?

2) Use file geodatabase

Use geodatabase or shapefile directly, since they support spatial and property query. But we wonder the performance?

Comment: How does your application work to access the data? If you use ArcObjects, the way you make your spatial/attribute queries will be the same regardless if you have an Oracle or ESRI file geodatabase. I don't know what performance you expect, but ESRI GDB are easy to get started and very efficient, especially if you use spatial indexes.

Answer (score 0):

**Technology:**

A combination of GeoServer, Openlayers & Oracle-spatial should work for you. If you want to cut-off licence cost, then PostgreSQL is a good option.

**Functioning**

For different-2 needs of spatial analysis, you can create functions/procedures in Oracle-spatial and then display data in browser using Openlayers. Geoserver works as GIS server, which serves WFS/WMS data as requested. Refer - [Geoserver](http://www.geoserver.org) and      [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/)

**Performance**

Need not to worry with above set of technologies.